# Notebook freezes when running Chrome: how can I limit the RAM available to Chrome?

Tags: 12.10, google-chrome, ram

I run Chrome on my laptop and it randomly freezes shortly after opening a new tab. It is a rather old notebook (MSI Megabook GX600 Extreme) with a Core2Duo and 2GB RAM. It runs Ubuntu 12.10 64Bit.

As soon as the interface locks up, massive read / writes seem to occur as the hard drive starts to get noisy. In another thread, someone recommend running `free -m`, which showed memory being fully used with only 50MB? Free and swap being used 1500MB of 2000MB.

How can I prevent Chrome from locking up the system like that? Will limiting the  memory available to it help?

Comment: I like the answer here: [Is it possible to limit the memory an application is allowed to use?](http://superuser.com/a/49612/151227)